# Такт как единица измерения

Tags: ассемблер, процессор

С коллегами обсуждаем до смешного простой вопрос: чем является такт работы процессора?
Википедия уточняет:

> В самом первом приближении тактовая частота характеризует производительность подсистемы (процессора, памяти и пр.), то есть количество выполняемых операций в секунду.

Обсуждаются два варианта:

- изменение значения бита (одного)
- ассемблерная операция (над рядом битов)

Благодарю!

Comment: IMHO более правильно обратить внимание на другую цитату

        Такт процессора или такт ядра процессора — промежуток между двумя импульсами тактового генератора, который синхронизирует выполнение всех операций процессора.

из той же Википедии.

--

Тут можно добавить, что в разных устройствах процессора могут использоваться разные тактовые частоты (обычно кратные).

Напрямую связывать один такт процессора ни с изменением одного бита, ни с одной ассемблерной операцией в большинстве современных процессоров не следует.

Comment: @avp комментарий вполне сойдет за ответ.

Comment: Тем более, современные «суперскалярные» архитектуры означают, что за «один такт» происходит кусочек отработки целой цепочки команд, некоторые из которых могут и никогда не быть выполнены на самом деле. В общем, такт — эфемерное понятие.

Comment: @VladD, почему эфемерное? Вполне ощутимое, а вот время обработки отдельной инструкции - да, вполне может варьироваться от 0 до каких-то космических значений (если, например, случился cache miss или чего похлеще).

Comment: @gecube: эфемерность его в том, что оно мало отражается в ощутимых программистом характеристиках компьютера. Например, скорости вычисления данной операции (как мы выяснили, она «размазана» по нескольким тактам).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Такт работы - это такт работы, т.е. промежуток времени между двумя соседними "пиками" некоего задающего тактового сигнала. Увы, без него не обойтись, т.к. схемы у нас цифровые и нам нужно фиксировать состояние сигналов.
Физически к изменению битов и выполнению команд такт относится опосредованно. Во-первых, разные блоки процессора работают на разной частоте. Но если рассматривать простейший случай, то одна команда выполняется минимум за один такт работы исполнительного у-ва. Всякие команды типа умножения или деления могут выполняться за сотни тактов. Во-вторых, общение с внешним миром у процессора происходит через шины, например, шину данных. У этой шины есть разрядность, например, 64 бит. Опять же в простейшем случае мы можем по этой шине передать за единицу времени кол-во информации равное произведению частоты на битность. Т.е. за такт можно сделать одну передачу, при этом все 64 бита передаются одновременно

Еще раз поясню, что "кол-во тактов" - это по сути единица измерения времени.
Связь со временем через частоту:

<Время> = <кол-во тактов> / <частота>

Comment: @gecube, а дополните свой ответ рассказом о конвейере исполнения команд, суперскалярности и разных задержках при обращении к разным уровням памяти (кэшам).

Comment: Поддерживаю, интересен ведь более сложный и более реальный случай.

Answer (score 6):

Если говорить про такт у процессора - это

> промежуток между двумя импульсами тактового генератора

Нас так учили в университете. Когда разрабатывал калькулятор на схемах, тактом был импульс сигнала.., и я соглашусь с [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)

Но если отвечать на вопрос **`Такт как единица измерения`** это:

> отдельная стадия (временной промежуток) какого-либо циклического процесса

и тут не важно, выполняется одна операция, или комплекс операций, изменяется 1 бит или несколько бит.

Answer (score 1):

Генератор тактовой частоты (генератор тактовых импульсов) генерирует электрические импульсы заданной частоты (обычно прямоугольной формы) для синхронизации различных процессов в цифровых устройствах ЭВМ.
Тактовые импульсы часто используются как эталонная частота — считая их количество, можно, например, измерять временные интервалы.
[ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

ГТЧ необходим, чтобы множество процессов того же процессора выполнялось последовательно, сначала установка адреса команды на шину адреса, затем через 2 такта чтение данных с шины данных, через 80 тактов выполнение декодирования считанной команды и так далее.

Число тактов произведённых генератором с момента подачи питания (включения компьютера) хранится в специальном счётчике, который можно читать.

Схема прямоугольного импульса
[image: Схема прямоугольного импульса]

Answer (score -2):

я думаю,

> ассемблерная операция (над рядом битов)

это последовательная операция (рассматриваем в контексте одноядерной машины), потому приходим к определению, что тактовая частота - это количество выполняемых операций в секунду. Хотя если операция над рядом бит делается за 1 такт(например умножение) - значит кол-во байт в этой операции не учитывается

Comment: Бред. Прошу более точно аргументировать свою позицию

Comment: >Хотя если операция над рядом бит делается за 1 такт(например умножение) - значит кол-во байт

умножение за ОДИН такт???

Comment: да легко, если оно табличное и таблица внутри процессора. Правда ещё обычно как минимум три такта нужно.